# Curl GET/POST raw data inclusive of headers?

Tags: http, curl, http-headers, http-post

Is there a way in command-line `curl` to POST or GET (insert your favorite HTTP method) data to a URL and include in the raw posted data header values instead of issuing the `-H` options?

For instance:

```
$curl --data-binary @- http://server.com/foo/bar <<EOF
X-Foo: Foo
X-Bar: Bar and a lot of random characters
Accept-Encoding: bzip2

My-raw-binary-data-here...
EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, there's no way. curl is a HTTP client that does the HTTP for you. Use 'nc' (netcat) or similar if you want to craft your full request more freely.

Comment: *I* know that. But I also know that curl only allows you to custom the request headers with -H and not "raw", hence my suggestion! =)